# Камин, топливник и очаг

Tags: значение

Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между камином, топливником и очагом? Какое слово более общее, какое более частное? В каком значении совпадают?

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее общим является термин "очаг". Очагом может служить и профессионально сработанный камин, и сложенная из кирпичей или камня плита, и наспех собранное из камней сооружение в пещере, где поддерживают огонь и готовят пищу. Более того, "очаг" может использоваться и в переносном смысле слова: "родной очаг" – метафора родного дома, обжитого пространства.

Топливник – это деталь камина (выложенная из огнеупорного кирпича ниша, в которой сгорает топливо).